# Egit repository not found installing from Android Developer Bundle

Tags: eclipse, adt, egit

I'm using the new ADT Bundle for Windows with eclipse and Android SDK embedded.
I'm trying to install eGit from one of its repository:

- Main P2 Repository: http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates
- Juno P2 Repository: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

I find it in both repository, but when installing it i get the error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was: (profile=profile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=).
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,com.sun.syndication,0.9.0.v200803061811
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.lang,2.6.0.v201205030909
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth,3.2.300.v20120523-2004
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity,0.9.1.v20120412-0100
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity.core,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications,0.9.1.v20120412-0100
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.core,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories,0.9.1.v20120412-0100
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.ui,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.screenshots,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.team,0.9.1.v20120412-0100
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.core,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.tasks.ui,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.ui,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.core,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.core,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.resources.ui,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.index.core,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.index.ui,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.search,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.team.ui,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn_feature,3.8.2.v20120916-1200
>
> No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jdom,1.1.1.v201101151400

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is a known issue for all plugins which don't come with the ADT bundle. According to [this issue (which actually is addressing some question about installing phonegap)](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/issues/detail?id=97) by design the ADT-bundle doesn't support extensions. And they don't seem to want to change that behavior. If you need the plugins, I recommend installing a different version of Eclipse.